# Proof of Fubini's Thorem, measure of a set is zero

Tags: real-analysis

How do I proof Fubini's theorem: A measurable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^p = \mathbb{R}^1 \times \mathbb{R^{p-1}}$ must have measure zero if it intersects each hyperplane in a set of $(p-1)$ dimensional measure zero.

I intuitively understand what this means. For example if I have a line crossed with a plane, this will give us the volume of a cube.

I was also given a hint $m(A)=\int dx_1...dx_p$

So I kinda see the relation between these two because they both represent the same volume

Comment: Hint: Proof by contradiction: take a measurable set with positive measure, and construct a non-negative measurable function (so you can use Tonelli's Theorem) to deconstruct its integral into pieces.

Comment: That's not Fubini's theorem. Rather your result follows easily from Fubini's theorem.